# Characterizing the primes which don't divide any Pell-Lucas number(s)

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, divisibility

For integer $n$, let $P_n$ be a Pell number, and $Q_n$ its companion. Is there a characterization of the prime numbers $p$ which don't divide any $Q_n$?

By brute-force search, I found that this appears to be true for *all* primes $p \equiv 5\!\pmod{8}$. I was going to conjecture [and eventually prove] that this was the complete characterization… until I discovered that it's *also* true for $p=137$. Are there any other such primes (*i.e.* $\not\equiv 5\!\pmod{8}$?

Note: I have skimmed through the relevant section (IV) of Ribenboim's *The Little Book of Bigger Primes*, but the answer isn't explicit there, and I wanted to make sure I wasn't reinventing the wheel before I go reinvent this wheel.

EDIT: In Ribenboim [p. 57], it says

> if $p \nmid 2DQ$, $(Q\mid p)=1$, and $(D \mid p) = -(-1 \mid p)$, then $p$ [is such a prime]. This does not determine, without a further analysis, whether a prime $p$, such that $p \nmid 2DQ$, $(Q\mid p)=1$, and $(D \mid p) = (-1 \mid p)$ belongs, or does not belong, to [the set of such primes].

This is a description in the context of general Lucas sequences. In the particular case of the Pell numbers (and companions), the relevant constants are $Q=-1$ and $D=8$. So Ribenboim is saying that primes $p \equiv 5\!\pmod{8}$ are certainly that in set (hence a proof of my initial ``conjecture''), but that nothing immediately eliminates or characterizes the primes $p=137,\dots(?)$ that are *also* in that set. I was/am just hoping someone else has already done the heavy lifting on this one.

Comment: There is a 1996 article by Pieter Moree that confirms that the density of primes that divide any number in the Pell sequence is 17/24, consistent with my answer below. See my follow-up question and new answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, $x^2 - 2 y^2 = \pm 1.$ We want to know about primes dividing $x,$ which will then divide $2 y^2 \pm 1.$ If prime $p \equiv 5 \pmod 8,$ then 
$2y^2 - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod p$ is impossible, as $2y^2  \equiv 1 \pmod p$ implies $(2|p) = 1,$ which is false. Also  $2y^2 + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod p$ is impossible, as $2y^2  \equiv -1 \pmod p$ implies $(-2|p) = 1,$ which is false.

Other than that, I would emphasize **projective** Pisano periods; mod 5, the sequence $1,3,7,17,41,99$ becomes $1,3,2,2,4,...$ where the quadruple $3,2,2,4$ is of type $-A,A,A,3A \pmod 5$ for $A=2.$ So we have a nonzero multiple of $1,3$ before getting a $0,$ which is a hands on way to show it never equals $0.$ Mod 137, within two dozen steps we get $37,100,100,26 \pmod {137}$ before seeing any $0,$ so that does it. We need only note the pair $100,100$ to have our conclusion.

Maybe there is a way to show all $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ do eventually divide some $x,$ not sure.

Evidently the misses are 5 mod 8 and a selection of 1 mod 8. So, worth looking at proof for 3 mod 4.

It appears that the peculiar primes are all of the form $p = x^2 + 128 y^2,$ about two thirds of those. I am, so far, unable to find a quadratic form that represents the peculiar primes $137, 521, 569,593,$ and nothing else. The figure $2/3$ suggests Chebotarev density, I suspect there is a polynomial with integer coefficients, call it degree $n,$ such that these numbers are precisely those for which there are $n$ distinct roots $\pmod p.$ Not so easy to find the polynomial, though.

Meanwhile, it appears that if a prime is either $(4,4,9)$ or $(4,4,33)$ it is ordinary, does divide some Pell companion. Put another way, if either $p = x^2 + 8 y^2$ with both $x,y$ odd, or  $p = x^2 + 32 y^2$ with both $x,y$ odd, then $p$ divides some Pell companion.

---

```
137    1    100
521    1    235
569    1    86
593    1    77
857    1    650
953    1    511
1321    1    257
1777    1    1002
1993    1    1159
2129    1    1757
2153    1    1921
2377    1    1134
2521    1    2450
2729    1    1627
2777    1    190
2833    1    1476
3001    1    1648
3209    1    484
3361    1    2461
3761    1    604
3929    1    226
4073    1    3524
4177    1    3720
4289    1    3761
4649    1    2803
4657    1    1912
4721    1    1697
4729    1    3364
4889    1    730
4969    1    1076
5233    1    2253
5273    1    4329
5449    1    4814
5641    1    4212
5801    1    4656
6353    1    1392
6449    1    4595
6481    1    729
7001    1    1198
7417    1    4680
7673    1    7396
8089    1    2293
8273    1    6111
8297    1    6200
8329    1    1443
8377    1    8047
9161    1    3125
9281    1    586
9433    1    8419
9929    1    2102
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```

---

Comment: So "our conclusion" is that $p=137$ is indeed [now algebraically proven to be] in the set of non-5-mod-8 "solutions", or that $\{137\}$ is the _entire_ set?

Comment: it is in the set. no idea what the entire set would be. I guess I will run a program for projective orbits with $p \neq 5 \pmod 8.$

Comment: @ Will: Thanks!! I thought you might have answered my problem completely already, but a characterization of the set (or even some inkling of what that characterization might be) will be both helpful and necessary.

Comment: @KierenMacMillan, edited in the other primes up to 10,000. All 1 mod 8.

Comment: Just to confirm: the second number in your table is the mod 8 value, and the third number is the "Pisano pair"?

Comment: @KierenMacMillan yes. For primes $p \equiv 3 \pmod 8,$ the first $0 \pmod p$ occurs at position $p+1$ or a divisor of it, for primes $p \equiv 7 \pmod 8,$ the first $0 \pmod p$ occurs at position $p-1$ or a divisor of it. In either case position $p^2 -1 $ will be $0.$ This is the sort of rigid pattern that can usually be proved.

Comment: Ribenboim proves that there is a zero at $(p \pm 1)/2$, which supports what you've described. However, what I'm trying to prove is where the _first_ zero is, and that's not always the same. For example, for $p=59$, we have $Q_{10}=3363\equiv0\!\pmod{59}$, and that's the first zero. Here, $10=(p+1)/6$, not the guaranteed-for-all-p $(p+1)/2$.

Comment: no idea how to predict where the first 0 occurs.

Comment: So I guess the question is: How to determine which "first zeros" are strictly $(p \pm 1)/2$, and which are divisors…

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period and references there.

Comment: @KierenMacMillan, it appears all primes 1 mod 8 in the output above have an integer expression $p = x^2 + 128 y^2,$ and roughly two out of three such primes have the same behavior in your problem. This suggests Chebotarev density, but there is no guarantee that there is a single quadratic form that represents the set $137,521,569,...$ and nothing else.